# Access ungit on a remote server over http

Tags: git, apache, version-control, ubuntu-16.04, ungit

I have installed ungit on my VPS (Ubuntu 16.04 with apache server and several vhosts/projects). I am new to git so I thought using a visual GUI it will help my learning curve.

is it possible to access the ungit over http from my local pc?? ex; http://ungit.my-domain.com or http://my-domain.com:8448

Answer (score 0):

That should work, as long as your firewalls are configured correctly. You might want to configure a password for ungit as well (see https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit#configuring).